# OpenXML: Creating a workbook, then putting a validator in--vs. Opening a workbook, then putting a validator in

Tags: c#, openxml, openxml-sdk

The following method creates a new workbook, and inserts two validator dropdowns:

```
public static void ForValidator() {
 using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Create("validator output.xlsx", SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook)) {
  WorkbookPart workbookpart = myDoc.AddWorkbookPart();
  workbookpart.Workbook = new Workbook();
  WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookpart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
  SheetData sheetData_ = new SheetData();
  worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData_);
  Sheets sheets_ = myDoc.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new Sheets());
  sheets_.AppendChild(new Sheet() {
   Id = myDoc.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(myDoc.WorkbookPart.WorksheetParts.First()), SheetId = 1, Name = "Sheet1"
  });
  DataValidations dataValidations = new DataValidations();
  DataValidation dataValidation = new DataValidation() {
   Type = DataValidationValues.List, AllowBlank = true, SequenceOfReferences = new ListValue<StringValue>() { InnerText = "F2:F3" }
  };
  Formula1 formula = new Formula1();
  formula.Text = "\"Selection 1,Selection 2,Selection 3\"";
  dataValidation.Append(formula);
  dataValidations.Append(dataValidation);
  worksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(dataValidations);
 }
}
```

Can the same routine be modified to instead just open an existing "validator output.xlsx" file and do the same thing?

For over a week I've tried everything I know to try and have come up with nothing.  Thank you for any help.

Comment: Can you elaborate it "Can the same routine be modified to instead just open an existing "validator output.xlsx" file and do the same thing", I don't understand your question.

Comment: Thank you for replying.  The posted method creates a workbook from scratch and then adds a validator.  What I have failed to do after repeated attempts, is rewrite the method so that it opens a workbook that is already there in a path and then adds a validator.  (In other words, open vs. create.)

Comment: Alright, can you share your code which you tried so far.

Comment: The code I tried so far is every example I could find (around a dozen) on the internet of Validator drop-downs being added to a sheet using OpenXML.  But they are all doing it while creating a workbook to do it in, as opposed to the workbook being already there in a directory and just opening it.  All my attempts to port relevant snips of that to my situation have failed.  Some corrupt the workbook, some don't, but on none of them does a Validator appear.  It should be not very much more complicated than restating a few beginning lines in the posted sample, but all attempts failed.

Comment: My worry about putting failed attempts on this thread is that it will clutter the nature of the page, which is:  There is already a perfectly working sample above, and more concise than most--problem is that it is only for new workbooks (Create), as opposed to a condition where something is already there (Open).  I can't redesign that sample above to operate for a workbook that is already there.  Any solutions appreciated, probably not only by me.

Comment: When I was working with Word and wanted to add custom Pagination in already added Header, then I faced this problem. So you can also use a work around like "open the document A, create new document B, copy content of A to B and add whatever you want to add to B and then delete A." If you want a code I can share code with you.